# Merge two complex MYSQL queries

Tags: mysql

i want help on a way to merge two complex MYSQL queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    posts p
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  a.ID
        FROM    posts a
                INNER JOIN post_tags b
                    ON a.ID = b.post_ID
        WHERE   a.post LIKE '%mmmm%' AND
                b.tagname IN ('#test','#iseeyou')
        GROUP   BY ID
        HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagname) = 2
    ) sub ON p.ID = sub.ID
ORDER   BY p.upvotes DESC, p.unix_timestamp DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT p.*, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes)
 / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) / (upvotes + downvotes))
 / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS ci_lower_bound 
 FROM posts p WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 
 AND p.unix_timestamp BETWEEN 1363023402 AND 1363109802 ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
```

A small table definition is given at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56c63/1)

Actually, the first one is a search query and the second one gives the most popular results based on votes in the last 24 hours, so i want use the search query based on the formula used in the second one and also the time range

Comment: just for curiosity :),why u dont use stored procedure to do so the

Comment: Why do you want to merge them at all?

Comment: @NetStarter i am not sure how to use a stored procedure for this.

Comment: @tombom Actually, the first one is a search query and the second one gives the most popular results based on votes in the last 24 hours, so i want use the search query based on the formula used in the second one and also the time range

Comment: you can do it by creating a temporary table and joining the same one in your stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimal changes something like this (if I have understood what you want correctly)

```
SELECT  p.*, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes)
 / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) / (upvotes + downvotes))
 / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS ci_lower_bound 
FROM    posts p
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  a.ID
        FROM    posts a INNER JOIN post_tags b  ON a.ID = b.post_ID
        WHERE   a.post LIKE '%mmmm%' AND b.tagname IN ('#test','#iseeyou')
        GROUP   BY ID
        HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagname) = 2
    ) sub ON p.ID = sub.ID
WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 
AND p.unix_timestamp BETWEEN 1363023402 AND 1363109802 
ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
```

Possibly a touch more efficient to swap around the WHERE clause on the subselect (the leading % on the like will not use an index, hence probably more efficient to join that against the easily indexed check on post_tags))

```
SELECT  p.*, ((upvotes + 1.9208) / (upvotes + downvotes) - 1.96 * SQRT((upvotes * downvotes)
 / (upvotes + downvotes) + 0.9604) / (upvotes + downvotes))
 / (1 + 3.8416 / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS ci_lower_bound 
FROM    posts p
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  a.ID
        FROM    post_tags b STRAIGHT_JOIN posts a ON a.ID = b.post_ID
        WHERE   a.post LIKE '%mmmm%' AND b.tagname IN ('#test','#iseeyou')
        GROUP   BY ID
        HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagname) = 2
    ) sub ON p.ID = sub.ID
WHERE upvotes + downvotes > 0 
AND p.unix_timestamp BETWEEN 1363023402 AND 1363109802 
ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
```

Comment: i used the same that you suggested and got an empty result but what i did was search within a time range that did not satisfy the tagnames so thought i was wrong. And now, seeing your answer it just struck my mind. You have enlightened me my friend :)

Comment: how do i find out the difference between the performance of the two versions that you suggested? i checked with `EXPLAIN` but it seemed same. i mean what would you suggest i should go with?

Comment: I would hope that normally MySQL would recognise the issue and optimise it away. But sometimes it fails to do this hence occasionally a STRAIGHT_JOIN can be useful to force the order of the JOIN